# Register and Login Multiple Users With the Same Firstname and Lastname

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a register-login system, but I'm facing the following problem:
- I can have two (or more) employees with the same firstname and the same lastname, and *possibly* with the same password, each located either in the same location, or different. When I'm trying to register them, obviously, there aren't problems, but when I want to login them, the problems arise.

Users table:

```
id int (11) A_I P_K,
firstname varchar (50),
lastname varchar(50),
password varchar(150)
```

Register.php

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=xxx', 'root', '');

$fname = isset($_POST['fname]) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
$lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
$pass  = isset($_POST['pass']) ? password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT) : '';

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users SET fname=?,lname=?,pass=?');
$stmt->execute([$fname,$lname,$pass]);
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Let's say the following users will register:

```
fname=aaa lname=bbb pass=123456 // password_hash(123456) = hash1
fname=aaa lname=bbb pass=123456 // password_hash(123456) = hash2
```

Login.php

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=xxx', 'root', '');

$fname = isset($_POST['fname]) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
$lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
$pass  = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname=? AND lname=?');
$stmt->execute([$fname,$lname]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    if (password_verify($pass, $row->pass)) {
        echo $row->fname,' ',$row->lname,'<br/>',$row->pass,"<br/>";
        // header('Location: app.php');
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

If I run the Login.php script, I will get the following output:

```
aaa bbb
$2y$10$Onkd3S06bOuOuyEH0/I9Be4jry1G8uIXgb3LxwroBZfZzywHKA6Eq (== hash1)

aaa bbb
$2y$10$ss0n1iBYPN4LG2VLP90Yc.vH109Y1Lq54X0bI/TGS242Hn/VkGwVi (== hash2)
```

And my question is, how can i differentiate the two users, so they can successfully log in in the app.php page, where I must display their credentials and other personal infos, which obviously differs from one user to another? Thanks!

LE: If I try with `LIMIT 1` for the login query, then it will display only the first record which will be found in the db.

Comment: Add a (unique) `username` field to your table and get people to log in using that. They can still have a `firstname` and `lastname`, for profile purposes.

Comment: add user's email if possible, that way you can easily identify user

Comment: @halfer Yes, I was thinking the same, but this system is more like "official", and not "forum like", where any user can choose any username they like. So I need to login them with their firstname and lastname.

Comment: That won't work. You could use firstname and lastname normally, and if you find that resolves to multiple entries, ask the user in a second step what their email is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users have the same firstname, the same lastname and the same password, you can't decide which user from the database is the correct. You need to give them one unique part. Maybe a loginname or an emailaddress

Answer (score 1):

You could use another unique field in your table like a username or an email, this way you'll be sure to get the right account even if the last & first name differ

Answer (score 0):

Really you need to assign each user a unique id to handle situations such as this. How you generate the id is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is is compulsory that you will not force users to have a `username`?

You can have `email` also, it is always different.

Most of the sites currently either force user to have unique `username` or `email`.

`email` is a must unique as it is the point of contact for the user from site administrator.